# search error: [index_not_found_exception] no such index in elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have **index not found exception** when the first time I run my code for index creation,But second time it working good.

Here is my code

```
function searchIndex(callback){

    client.search({  
        index: 'postgrescredentials-01',
        type: 'credentials',
        body: {
            query: {
                match: { 
                    "username": "postgres" 
                }
            },
        }
    },function (error, response,status) {

        if (error){
            console.log("search error: "+error)
        }
        else { 
            response.hits.hits.forEach(function(hit){
                var ciphertext = hit._source.pswrd
                callback(ciphertext)
            })
        }

    });
};

exports.searchIndex = searchIndex;
```

---

```
encryptObj = enpyt.encrypt(password,function(encrypted){

    client.index({  
        index: 'postgrescredentials-01',
        id: '101',
        type: 'credentials',
            body: {
            "username": "postgres",
            "pswrd": encrypted

            }
    },function(err,resp,status) {
            console.log(resp);
    });
    console.log("The encrypted password is-->",encrypted)       
    //Get The Searched Encrypted value 
    search.searchIndex(function(encryptedValue){        
        //Get the Decrypted Value
        decrypt.decrypt(encryptedValue,function(decryptedValue){        
            console.log("The decrypted password is-->",decryptedValue); 
        });
    });
    })
```

Any idea why i am getting index not found exception at first time of execution.